# Google Voice does not provide spoken prompts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-now

I'm using a samsung s7 and google voice in Always Listen mode.

I can say Ok Google, then  "text john". 
 It works, but  google voice does not SAY "ready", " ready ro send?"

On Straighttalk on verizon network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say Ok Google and go to Settings in Google voice and turn on Voice Output to Always.

[image]